# Solve $a^2 + b^2 = t, 2ab = 1/t$ for $a,b$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I want to solve
$$
a^2 + b^2 = t \\
2ab = 1/t
$$
for $a$ and $b$ in terms of $t$. Wolfram [solves it](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=solve+%7Ba%5E2+%2B+b%5E2+%3D+t,+2ab+%3D+1%2Ft%7D+for+a,b) but the solution is very dirty.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$$
\left \{ \begin{array}{rclr}
  a^2+b^2 &=& t & \qquad \cdots \cdots (1) \\
  2ab &=& \dfrac{1}{t} & \qquad \cdots \cdots (2) \\
\end{array}
\right.$$

From $(1)$, $$t \ge 0$$

By $AM \ge GM$, $$t\ge \frac{1}{t} \implies t\ge 1$$

$(1)+(2)$, $$(a+b)^2=t+\frac{1}{t} \implies |a+b|=\sqrt{t+\frac{1}{t}}$$

$(1)-(2)$, $$(a-b)^2=t-\frac{1}{t} \implies |a-b|=\sqrt{t-\frac{1}{t}}$$

Since $2ab=\dfrac{1}{t} \in (0,1]$,
$$
\begin{pmatrix} a \\ b \end{pmatrix}=
\begin{pmatrix}
  \frac{1}{2} \left( \sqrt{t+\frac{1}{t}} \pm \sqrt{t-\frac{1}{t}} \right) \\
  \frac{1}{2} \left( \sqrt{t+\frac{1}{t}} \mp \sqrt{t-\frac{1}{t}} \right)
\end{pmatrix}
\quad \text{or} \quad
\begin{pmatrix}
  \frac{1}{2} \left( -\sqrt{t+\frac{1}{t}} \pm \sqrt{t-\frac{1}{t}} \right) \\
  \frac{1}{2} \left( -\sqrt{t+\frac{1}{t}} \mp \sqrt{t-\frac{1}{t}} \right)
\end{pmatrix}$$

> **P.S.**
>
> The solution by Wolfram Alpha isn't "dirty", it takes care the sign of $2ab$ after simplification.
>
> Eliminating $b$ gives biquadratic in $a$:
>
> $$4t^2a^4-4t^3a^2+1=0 \implies a^2=\frac{t^2 \pm \sqrt{t^4-1}}{2t}$$
>
> $$
> \begin{pmatrix} a \\ b \end{pmatrix}=
> \begin{pmatrix}
>   \sqrt{\dfrac{t^2 \pm \sqrt{t^4-1}}{2t}} \\
>   \sqrt{\dfrac{t^2 \mp \sqrt{t^4-1}}{2t}}
> \end{pmatrix}
> \quad \text{or} \quad
> \begin{pmatrix}
>   -\sqrt{\dfrac{t^2 \pm \sqrt{t^4-1}}{2t}} \\
>   -\sqrt{\dfrac{t^2 \mp \sqrt{t^4-1}}{2t}}
> \end{pmatrix}
> $$

Answer (score 3):

$$(a+b)^2 = a^2+b^2+2ab = t + \frac{1}{t}$$
so we have
$$
a + b = \pm\sqrt{t+\frac{1}{t}}
$$
and proceed.

Answer (score 3):

$${a^2 + b^2 = t \\}$$
$${2ab = 1/t}$$

$${(a+b)^2}=t+1/t$$
$${a+b= \pm\sqrt{t+\frac{1}{t}}}$$

Also,
$${(a-b)^2=t-1/t}$$
$${a-b= \pm\sqrt{t-\frac{1}{t}}}$$

Just make some addition and subtraction now to get the answer. I shall let you conclude.